# Axis2 + spring + mongodb

Tags: wso2

I am trying to integrate Axis2/Spring/Mongodb on wso2 application server.
I got spring context hooked up to the axis2 webservice. Once I am trying to access 
MongoDB,the following error occurs

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolder
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 53 more
```

The error should be pretty straight forward to solve, fix my dependencies/copy the jar spring-tx jar file in somekind of a lib folder....

It seems that it is not so obvious with wso2 application server. Where should I put my jar files in order to have them loaded ?

Many thanks,
Skip

Comment: Do you use maven to manage your dependencies?

Comment: Yes I do, I also managed to have maven embedding the dependencies in the aar file.